# Why does a Keyless chuck sometimes stick?

Tags: drill, stuck, chuck, bit

I noticed that Keyless chucks in cheap drills tend to become stuck often, but I've always wonder why does this happen.

Is it due to overtightening the chuck?

Are low quality drill bits a factor to consider?

Is it going on some heat issue (spot-welding like) between its metal components?

I am aware that this issue is also related to drilling on concrete with a low power electric drill but, again, I'm unable to find a valid reason for it.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Yep, sorry, a keyless chuck of those operated with just one hand.

Comment: Even the  keyless chuck on my expensive drill  gets stuck occasional. It is a matter of torque.

Comment: I have a cordless hammer drill that's over a decade old and it hasn't seized in years and I use it every day. Why? because it was $400 and it says Dewalt on it.

Comment: Keep the chuck clean (*keep* it clean: keep crap from getting in there; don't actually clean it), and **occasionally run it full close to full open a few times to de-burr itself while also facing down to let junk out**. If all materials are considered equal (which they aren't... $$$), then all that's left are tolerances, which is an engineering question. - How to keep a chuck in working order? *work* it. And *a, single, drop* of oil every three years or so.

Comment: 'occasionally' ... Now that I think about it I do it almost every day. Maybe that's why it still works and doesn't seize. It's also full metal construction, so when it has seized, channel locks or pipe wrenches work w/o destroying it. - On a cheap drill half of the chuck is plastic, or covered in plastic, where it should just be thicker metal and less likely to deform. Cheap also have less power, so a situation where yours would be stuck and stall out, I'd just have to put a glove on because with a fresh battery my drill can overpower my naked grip.

Comment: Interesting point on metal crap being the culprit, never thought of it. I will certainly clean it as you suggest or maybe using the air blow gun. However, metal crap can't be the case in another, much more expensive, (new) drill from Metabo, being locked after just a few drills; in this case: two-handed full metal keyless chuck. I've been using power drills for 20 years and still can't figure it out all the causes for this issue. Tolerances and materials certanly matters also. And I absolutely agree with you on Dewalt, have also one of them and they're great, well, drills and anything else.

Comment: @Mazura  The expensive one I mentioned is an all metal chuck, i use it several times a week and it also say Dewalt on it.   Occasionally it does get over torqued during use.